# How to increase the gap between words in scrolling "marquee" text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Im using jQuery to create a horizontal scrolling "marquee" text, trying to figure out how to increase the size of the gap between the phrases, see my example below "HEY THERE".

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('.marquee_text').marquee({
    direction: 'left',
    duration: 20000,
    gap: 0,
    delayBeforeStart: 0,
    duplicated: true,
    startVisible: true
});
});
```

```css
.marquee_text {
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 10vw;
    line-height: 1em;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-family: "Alliance No 2", Sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.marquee-container{
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 11vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery.Marquee/1.5.0/jquery.marquee.min.js"></script>

<div class="marquee-container">
<div class="marquee_text"> HEY THERE HEY THERE HEY THERE HEY THERE  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You clearly know how to use CSS, so... just add the [css property for word spacing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-spacing)? This would have been more than easy enough to find with even a casual web search, no need to ask on stackoverflow =)

Comment: Sorry I didnt explain it very well, ive edited my question to make it clearer. The word spacing CSS would work fine for single words, but I need it to work on phrases, so in my example "HEY THERE", then I would need a gap before the next "HEY THERE"

Comment: just wrap your sentences in `<span>` and set the CSS for `.marquee_text span + span`? "Sentences" are not a thing in html/css, if you have something more complex than "letters or words", the solution is to use markup to group your content. With that said: also remember to update your post to include that tiny bit more information. Instead of talking about `HEY THERE HEY THERE HEY THERE`, I'd suggest using something like `Welcome to my site Welcome to my site Welcome to my site`, so that it's at least obvious where that extra space should have been.

Comment: Cool thanks Ive just added this to the CSS - `.marquee_text span { padding-right: 5vw;}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [word-spacing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-spacing) property! Unfortunately there isn't and nth property for this so here is an alternate solution:

Or you can also wrap the phrases in a span and apply a `padding-right: 150px;` to the span, or whatever padding you wish.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('.marquee_text').marquee({
    direction: 'left',
    duration: 20000,
    gap: 0,
    delayBeforeStart: 0,
    duplicated: true,
    startVisible: true
});
});
```

```css
.marquee_text {
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 10vw;
    line-height: 1em;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-family: "Alliance No 2", Sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    /*word-spacing: 2em;*/
}
span { /*if you don't use the word-spacing, you can put spans in between each phrase and add a padding-right */
padding-right: 200px;
}

.marquee-container{
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 11vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery.Marquee/1.5.0/jquery.marquee.min.js"></script>

<div class="marquee-container">
<div class="marquee_text"> <span>HEY THERE</span><span>HEY THERE</span><span> HEY THERE<span></span> HEY THERE  </div>
</div>
```